# Handling Expired Access Token in Implicit Grant Flow Oauth2

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

We have implemented authentication as specified in the [C# Teams Sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-csharp).Once the `access_token` expires we have to re-prompt the user to login.

Currently, the `access_token` expires in 1 hour.

Scopes:

- `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`
- `openid`
- `Mail.Send`
- `Sites.Read.All`

When we request refresh token [per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit), it gives an `access denied` error.

Is there a way to refresh the token instead of prompting the user to login again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using implicit grant after the token has been expired you should login again there will be no other option to get the access token.

If you use code grant then you will get **RefreshToken** along with **AccessToken** you can update get the new **AccessToken** using the **RefreshToken**. Please follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) for Code grant implementation

Comment: Thanks Srinivas. As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-implicit#refreshing-tokens - we may raise a new request for access token silently- without prompting the user. We tried this in C#, but gives a Access Denied error. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vinu sorry for the delay in response. For the silent authentication you need to use adal.js in the client side.If we want to raise a request for access token then you are supposed to use the client side libraries not c#.